# Easy way to show an image from a S3 bucket on a web front end through API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

Is there any way of doing this? I want to create an alexa skill in which , depending on the request, a picture from the S3 bucket is showed on the web front end. Just on the front end created by the API gateway. 
I was hoping this tutorial would help me:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/
I excluded the resizing, but it didn't work anyway. All i get is that the picture

Maybe this is a littbit unclear, but I want it to work like in this exmaple: https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/01/31/how-to-return-html-from-aws-api-gateway-lambda/ bu instead a html text there should be a picture.

I would be so happy if someone could help me with that.

Comment: Alexa skills are triggered by voice and answered by voice (well, Echo Show might change that). So, what is the "web front end" you mention? How is it related to the voice request? The example talks about serving HTML from API Gateway and does not mention Alexa.

Comment: You already seem to have a guide for showing the image and another one to show a HTML. You can add a image tag in the html with the image. That way you have a HTML with images. Can you explain a bit more?